# How to Draw a line over an image background?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development may any body guide  me how i can draw these **diagonal lines** over an image.

[image]

Comment: i want to make lines just i mentioned in above image

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't just modify the image itself to include the lines?

Comment: because i want to upload  low quality image that wilnt make web slow